# Assignment to constant variable error but it's assigned to let

Tags: javascript, html, import, export

I'm trying to export functions and change variables of 2 js code.
I'm currently working on a project and I need to make sure user is logged in before he can access content
I made two html one for main and one for login.
first Code looks like this:

```
import status from '/login.js';

const addhotel = document.getElementById("addhotel");
let online = null;
export default online = false;

addhotel.addEventListener('click', function(){
    
    if(online === true){
        console.log("You Can Add")
    }else{
        addhotel.setAttribute("href", "/loginForm.html")
        setTimeout(function(){submit()}, 10000)
    }
})
```

And second is This:

```
import online from '/app.js'

export const user = document.getElementById("user");
export const pass = document.getElementById("pass");
export const submit = document.getElementById("submit");
export let loggedIn = false;
export let id = 0;

submit.addEventListener("click", function(){
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:3000/users")
    .then((res) => {
        return res.json()
    }).then((data) => {
        if(user.value == data[0].user && pass.value === data[0].pass){
            console.log("welcome", data[0].user)
            loggedIn = true;
            id = data[0].id
        }
        else if(user.value == data[1].user && pass.value === data[1].pass){
            console.log("welcome", data[1].user)
            loggedIn = true;
            id = data[1].id
        }       
        else if(user.value == data[2].user && pass.value === data[2].pass){
            console.log("welcome", data[2].user)
            loggedIn = true;
            id = data[2].id
        }       
        else{
            user.style.border = "2px solid red"
            pass.style.border = "2px solid red"
        }
    })
    setTimeout(function(){status()}, 1000);
})

export default function status() {
    if(loggedIn === true){
        online = true;
    }else{
        online = false;
    }
}
```

and I still get error when online variable is declared to let Can anyone help me ??

Comment: Please post the exact error message and indicate which line it's happening on.

Comment: login.js:39 Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
    at status (login.js:39)
    at login.js:34


at line 39 is online variable and on 34 is submit function

Comment: The error is clearly coming from "login.js", yet you did not post that code!!

Comment: line:38  if(loggedIn === true){
 line:39       online = true;
line:40     }

Comment: i posted full login.js code that I have